# How to handle file openings by double click, while refusing multiple instances

Tags: c++, c++builder

Ok, so I have an application that - at start up - checks for other instances of the program using the Mutex "solution". So when I start the second instance of my program, I get a popup message telling me to ...  well whatever.

However, how do I handle it when I want to open a file in my already open instance, by double clicking the file in explorer? (Like Excel)
I guess that the solution must be some sort of message handler between the "old" instance and the new, where the new tells the old to open file xxx. Or is there any other way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will need to send a message to the first instance to tell it to open the file.  Use one of the IPC mechanisms available in Windows or your favorite class library.  A socket or pipe is the usual approach.

Comment: That is the old school way of doing things. The modern solution is to let Windows handle everything for you. Add a COM server to your app that supports the `IDropTarget` and `IDataObject` interfaces, then you can register that COM server as a DropTarget for the file extension(s) that you are clicking on. If the server is already running, Windows will pass an `IDataObject` object containing the filename(s) directly to the existing app instance without having to start a new instance. If the server is not running yet, Windows will auto-start it and then pass the `IDataObject` to it.

Comment: Not only is this more efficient, but it also allows you to support multiple filenames at a time, various OLE drag-and-drop scenarios (drag on the app window, drag on the app .exe file itself, etc), even virtualized and non-file data, all with a single implementation of the `IDropTarget` interface.